# Can we wirte with(nolock) in update statement joining with other tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables, let say Main,transactions table

Main :

```
mainID Name  Active
1  sharath  1
2  kiran    0
3  ashish   1
```

Transaction :

```
TransID TransType status MainID IsActive
101      D         22    1       0
102      R         27    2       1
103      R         32    2       1
104      D         11    1       0
105      R         43    3       0
```

which update statement is preferable in these :

1)

```
Update TR
set  status  = 0,
     Isactive = 0
from Transaction TR
inner join main MN with(nolock) on MN.MainID = TR.MainID 
where MN.Isactive = 0
```

2)

```
Update TR
set  status  = 0,
     Isactive = 0
from Transaction TR
inner join main MN on MN.MainID = TR.MainID 
where MN.Isactive = 0
```

In first query, I made inner join with Main and used `with(nolock)` as I want to update the records for those MainID where Isactive = 0

In second query, without using `with(nolock)` I have written update statement.

which one is preferrable, n will do update without any errors in future also.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "preferable" as currently I can't understand why would you want to use `NOLOCK` in an update statement, this would give rise to the possibility of updating your table with "Dirty" data.

Comment: on main table,
there will be multiple update and delete statements are running on it in some SP's.
so without waiting till it set to free. i kept with(nolock) to fetch the data from that table.

Comment: The question is only really answerable by you. What is preferable to you, the possibility of a faster query, or a more accurate query? I personally do not have a preference as to how you want to update your own data...

Answer (score 1):

Using NOLOCK with SELECT will return data, that could be dirty . We can use this table hint to get results quickly when we are sure that dirty data is fine. But i do not see a reason why one should use NOLOCK on DML, as dirty data might get written to db and also committed.
Uncommitted transactions in main table might introduce dirty data into Transaction table.